# Проверка JSON - удаление и добавление в БД

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, json

Нужна помощь с JSON и его взаимодействием с БД. 
Имеется к примеру такой JSON.

```
{
    "response": {
        "trade_offers_received": [
            {
                "tradeofferid": "1537239550",
                "accountid_other": 169029426
            },
            {
                "tradeofferid": "1537239438",
                "accountid_other": 169029426
            },
            {
                "tradeofferid": "1537239334",
                "accountid_other": 169029426
            },
            {
                "tradeofferid": "1537236218",
                "accountid_other": 169029426
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

Задача в том, что нужно парсить его в реальном времени, добавляя в базу по одному элементу с каждым обновлением страницы, пока не добавятся все элементы ("tradeofferid"), это проблема решена, но с трудом, а главная проблема сейчас в том, что не получается удалять те элементы из БД, которых уже нет в JSON, помогите правильно составить нужный вариант, мой код ниже:

```
    $tradesinfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeOffers/v1/?key='.$userinfo['keyuser'].'&get_received_offers=1&active_only=1'),true);
    $tradescount = count($tradesinfo['response']['trade_offers_received']);
    $stmtone = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM trades');
    $stmtone->execute();
    $tradesinfo = $tradesinfo['response']['trade_offers_received'];
   //Тут все очень костыльно, работает не так, как хотелось бы 
    $tradeinfo = $tradesinfo[$stmtone->rowCount()];
    $steamids = reloads('[U:1:'.$tradeinfo['accountid_other'].']');
    $userofferinfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='.$usersinfo['keyuser'].'&steamids='.$steamids),true);
    $userinfo = $userofferinfo['response']['players'][0];
    // Попытка удалять из БД, а удаляет все строки
     while($rowone = $stmtone->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $arrs = in_array($rowone['tradeid'],$tradesinfo);
        if($arrs != $rowone['tradeid']){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM trades WHERE tradeid = :tradeid');
    $stmt->execute(Array('tradeid'=>$rowone['tradeid']));
        }
    } 
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM trades WHERE tradeid = :tradeid');
    $stmt->execute(Array('tradeid' => $tradeinfo['tradeofferid']));
    if($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO trades (tradeid,mysteamid,steamid,user,avatar,country,message) VALUES (:tradeid,:mysteamid,:steamid,:user,:avatar,:country,:message)');
    $stmt->execute(Array('tradeid' => $tradeinfo['tradeofferid'],'mysteamid' => $steamid,'steamid' => $steamids,'user' => $userinfo['personaname'],'avatar' => $userinfo['avatarmedium'],'country' => $userinfo['loccountrycode'],'message' => $tradeinfo['message']));
    }
```

Comment: Когда обновляете страницу, удаляйте всё из базы для данной продажи и добавляйте заново те, что содержаться в JSON. Как вариант решения. Можно ещё не добавлять в базу элементы пока не сформируется весь список предметов. Используйте в этом случае ajax

Comment: @ArchDemon, вот в том то и проблема, что удалять все из базы не выход, потому что полный парсинг очень требователен к ресурсам и очень редко необходим, так как JSON этот полностью редко обновляется, обычно добавля.тся 2-3 элемента, либо убавляюся

Comment: ну так и в чём проблема удаления 5 записей из базы и добавления 2-3 вместо 5? Я вас не заставлю удалять вообще все элементы, а только те, которые в настоящий момент участвуют в продаже (например, у конкретного пользователя)

Comment: Можно поставить крон задачу, которая будет раз в 30 секундсоздавать новый json файл с помощью file_put_contents а запрос к базе просто пускай проверяет этот файл и обновляет таблицу.

Comment: А можно увидеть пример?